# Extern using pointer instead of array

Tags: c, extern

Suppose we have 2 files

1) file1.c

```
int Appples[10];
```

2) file2.c

```
extern int *Appples;
```

Is there any prob with this type of declaration except that i will have to handle size independently ?

Comment: Why not `extern int Apples[10];` ?

Comment: @Mahesh, Does it really affects behavior?

Comment: Yes, one problem: it's not valid. Don't do this.

Comment: @Alex Yes. If you like, I can add another answer with concrete examples and assembly code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in [C FAQs 6.1](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html)

> The type pointer-to-type-T is not the same as array-of-type-T. Use extern char a[].

while [this answer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) addresses the issue more specifically. The final point is: an array isn't a pointer and you shouldn't treat one as such.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable as:

```
extern int *Appples;
```

it needs to be defined as:

```
int *Appples = <initializer>;
```

not as:

```
int Appples[10];
```

If you want to define using:

```
int Appples[10];
```

It can be declared as:

```
extern int Appples[10];
```

or

```
extern int Appples[];
```